# Why isn't my JavaScript code sending a post request to the Flask server?

Tags: javascript, flask

Here is my Flask server:

```
from flask import Flask, request,  jsonify from main import *

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context='adhoc')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST']) 
def do_classification():
    try:
        data = request.get_json()
        user_input = data['input']
        prediction = classify(user_input)
        print(f'Received input "{user_input}" from chat server')
        return jsonify({'prediction': prediction})
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000)
```

And here is the JavaScript code (written within the  tags of the HTML file), this code is responsible for sending a string to the flask server:

```js
// Get the form and input elements
const form = document.getElementById('message-form');
const input = document.getElementById('message-input');

// Add an event listener to the form
form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => {
  // Prevent the default form submission behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the input value
  const message = input.value;

  // Create a new message element and add it to the output window
  const messageElement = document.createElement('div');
  messageElement.textContent = message;
  document.getElementById('chat-window').appendChild(messageElement);


  input.value = '';
  // send user input to the model
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:5000/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        input: message
      }),
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Request failed with status ' + response.status);
    }
    const prediction = await response.text();
    // Display the model's response in the chat window
    const modelMessageElement = document.createElement('div');
    modelMessageElement.textContent = prediction;
    document.getElementById('chat-window').appendChild(modelMessageElement);
  } catch (error) {
    // Display the error message in the chat window
    const errorMessageElement = document.createElement('div');
    errorMessageElement.textContent = 'Error: ' + error.message;
    document.getElementById('chat-window').appendChild(errorMessageElement);
  }

});
```

To summarize what I am trying to accomplish:

- The JS code is responsible for sending a string, "message" to the Flask server.
- The Flask server receives "message" and stores it in the variable "user_input", then sends
  "user_input" to the "classify" function.
- Whatever is returned from the "classify" function is supposed to be sent back to the JS program.

However, this is not working: I received and "Error: Failed to fetch" when I tried to run this.

Any idea why?

Flask is not printing that it received anything to the terminal window where it is being run.

Comment: So there is no error in the console and did you inspect the network request? Is there a CORs error?

Comment: Replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 Does that work?

Comment: @epascarello No CORs error, I checked dev console, and it shows `localhost` in red text, with an initiator that lead me to this piece of code `    const response = await fetch('https://localhost:5000/', {
`

Comment: Are you really running https on localhost? And code above is different than in your question. One above is missing the protocol. `await fetch('//localhost:5000'`

Comment: @epascarello @jarmod -- when i double click the `localhost` error in red, within dev console, it takes me to a page that says:
`This site can’t provide a secure connection127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: Wait, when I removed the SSL code from the Flask server, I am now receiving a CORs error. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Rather than fixing the CORS error, you should fix the reason why you aren't able to use SSL for both the HTML page and the Flask server.